# File field inside Grid field inside Low Variable - File is not saved

Tags: low-variables, grid

So I've seen similar questions to this one, but they dealt with P&T addons Matrix & Assets. The problem I am experiencing is with EE Native Grid & File fields when they are placed inside of a Low Variable.

The file is uploaded correctly, it's not a permissions issue. I can see the file in the file manager and use it in other fields on the site.

My Low Variable is a Grid type, and it's got a column that takes a file upload. When I select the file, it shows the thumbnail, but as soon as I click 'save changes', it is gone.

When I logged the DB queries that ran when saving the field, it showed that the file field is getting set to NULL.

I'm running EE 2.7.3 and LV 2.4.0

Comment: I just attempted manually adding the filename in the database - {filedir_1}somefilename.png - and it worked. So LV is not correctly writing the filename to the lv_grid_field_xx table...

Comment: LV just calls the Grid functions to process its fields, so it's more likely to be a Grid issue than a LV issue.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this. All my grid fields were set as required, so leaving any field empty when saving removed the images. Adding data to all fields (including images) and it saved ok.

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in the next version. In the meantime, if you make sure all columns are *not* required, you can avoid the issue, too.